# When using mysql to check for a value, it doesn't return anything?

Tags: php, mysql

So, I have a mysql table named: "cake_users"
Here's what it looks like and how it's structured

```
1 name1 4588yrue38r authkey114
2 name2 4o857398563 authkey124
3 name3 93784ee8753 authkey115
4 name4 12345678910 authkey164
id, name, hwid, authkey
```

I'm trying to run this query:

```
$hwidid = "'12345678910'";

$cakequery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cake_users WHERE hwid = {$hwidid}");
if(mysql_num_rows($cakequery) == 0) {
     echo 'FALSE';
} else {
    echo 'TRUE';
}
```

But it always echo's false even though `12345678910` is in the database?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Echo out your query. Run it directly in the database. Does it work? As an aside, I'd really recommend not using mysql_* functions as they are deprecated, and completely removed in PHP7. Use PDO or mysqli_* instead.

Comment: try this way:

`$hwidid = '12345678910';

$cakequery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cake_users WHERE hwid = '$hwidid'");`

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim Why? Strings don't have memory, PHP doesn't care how you created them.

Comment: I ran the SQL query via php my admin and it worked fine. I'll try to use mysqli_* instead of mysql_* and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Did you connect to the database correctly?

Comment: @Ryan: `"I ran the SQL query"` - *What* SQL query did you run?  What this one actually is, or what you assume it is?  Include the actual query being executed in the question.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I know but he has done this way: `$hwidid = "'12345678910'";` which is going to add the single quote with the value taking the whole thing as a string where his value is only the numbers without string.

Comment: I suspect this entire problem would become moot if you just use query parameters like one is supposed to...

Comment: No, it's still echo'ing false even though it's in the database..

Comment: When you use mysqli, do not use the query as is. Take advantage of it's features and allow it to bind your parameters, so you don't have to escape it yourself.

Comment: and I ran this: "SELECT * FROM cake_users WHERE hwid = '12345678910'

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim [Nope](https://eval.in/594562)

Comment: what is the data type of `hwid`? is it varchar (or some other type which supports strings) or int (or some other type which supports numbers)?
If it's int then remove the quotes from `'12345678910'`

Comment: You just posted the same question. The answer is still dont use `mysql_*`. They don't work with `mysqli`. Hiding the `mysqli` connection doesn't help and makes the question less useful. Auto downvote for duplication, of your own question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Error 500 while connecting to mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37994913/http-error-500-while-connecting-to-mysql)

Answer (score 2):

Hi I suggest you should `echo` your `query` and run into `phpmyadmin` or you should add `mysql_error` `function` to see if any error exist or not in `query` running. Also please use `mysqli` or `PDO`.

try this

```
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
$con = mysql_select_db('yourdatabasename');
if($con){

    $hwidid = '12345678910';
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cake_users WHERE hwid = '$hwidid'";
    //echo $sql;die; for debugging

    $cakequery = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_num_rows($cakequery) == 0) {
         echo 'FALSE';
    } else {
        echo 'TRUE';
    }

}else{

echo "no connection";

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other comments about using mysqli and more importantly PDO are correct, but a direct response to your problem: I think you have too many quotation marks around 12345678910

```
$hwidid = '12345678910';

$cakequery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cake_users WHERE hwid = '$hwidid'");
if(mysql_num_rows($cakequery) == 0) {
     echo 'FALSE';
} else {
    echo 'TRUE';
}
```